# Google AppEngine datastore config: reusable?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, config

The documentation about datastore config objects confuses me:

> "A configuration object can be used any number of times. You must create a separate configuration object for each datastore call that uses it."
>   [(from AppEngine doc)](http://code.google.com/intl/en/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queries.html#Setting_the_Read_Policy_and_Datastore_Call_Deadline)

So can I do something like this:

```
config = db.create_config(deadline=5)
db.put(someModels, config=config)
db.delete(someKeys, config=config)
```

Or do I have to do something like this:

```
config = db.create_config(deadline=5)
db.put(someModels, config=config)
config = db.create_config(deadline=5)
db.delete(someKeys, config=config)
```

?

Thanks

Comment: You're right, this is totally perplexing (and self-contradictory). I'll hunt someone down who knows and get you an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a left-over from when config options were changed by creating a RPC.  Each RPC could be used only once.  The new datastore [Configuration](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/datastore/datastore_rpc.py#384) objects can be used multiple times; parameters are now [read from them](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/datastore/datastore_rpc.py#959) and passed on.

For reference, when settings were passed by creating RPC objects the docs read:

> An RPC object can only be used once. You must create a separate RPC object for each datastore call that uses it.

Comment: That sounds right, Robert - thanks! I'll make sure the docs get fixed.

Comment: @Nick, cool.  Those two sentences aren't some of the clearer ones in the docs.  Looked like a good ol' fashion typo to me.